# Hover button Transition Delay

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

I'm maybe 2 weeks into coding so apologies if I don't format correctly (code and question itself).I am trying to set a delay for the time it takes the buttons to switch text. Thank you for the help!

I've tried googling this and youtube with no luck.
I have tried adding
transition
transition-delay

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
.column{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:55px;
  width:72px;
  z-index: 200;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.about,
.skills {
font-size:72px;
width: 10em;
text-align: left;
border:none;
background-color: black;
color:red;
}

.about:hover span {
display: none;
}

.about:hover:after {
transition-delay: 3s;
content: "ABOUT";

}

.skills:hover span {
display: none
}

.skills:hover:after {
content: "SKILLS"
}
```

```html
  <h1>
    <div class="column">
      <button class="about" data-hover="ABOUT">
        <span>
          I
        </span>
      </button>
      <button class="skills">
        <span>
          AM
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </h1>
```

Comment: Look up transition, not transition delay, to get started with transitions. MDN is a reliable source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would look into the `html` semantics a bit. Having `div` tags inside an `h1` doesn't make much sense. So consider changing the `h1` to a `div`. Also, the 3s delay is enormous. Think of something a bit faster, like 300ms.

The real issue is that `display` states and `transition` don't really work together since it swaps between states like `block` and `none`. But there are other solutions to this. You could use `position: relative;` on a parent `div` and give the children `position: absolute`. This way, you could make the transitions with `opacity` instead.

I have made an example for you so you can get the idea. I have commented on the CSS so you can follow up on what is happening.

```css
/* Lets give our spans some styling: */
span{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  max-width: 60ch;
}

/* Lets make the "container" position relative, 
   this way the absolute children will stay inside the container */
.hover-effect{
  position: relative;
}

/* Let's give both of the children position absolute */
.hover-effect span{
    position:   absolute;
    color:      black;
    opacity:    100%;
    transition: 300ms ease-in 300ms; /* Delay: 300ms*/
}

/* Let’s override the previous.
   This actually happens when we remove the hover, so we want to
   trigger this animation first, hence the delay of 0ms*/
.hover-effect span.on-hover{
  opacity:      0%;
  transition:   300ms ease-in 0ms;
}

/* When we hover the container, let's change both spans */
.hover-effect:hover span{
    color:              red;
    opacity:            0%;
    transition-delay:   0ms;
}

/* Let’s override the previous.
   When we hover on the container, the span with the class "on-hover"
   becomes visible, and we wait 300ms before it happens so that the 
   "disappearing" animation gets its time to trigger. */
.hover-effect:hover span.on-hover{
    opacity:            100%;
    transition-delay:   300ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-effect">
     <span>Try and hover over me</span>
     <span class="on-hover">Try and remove the hover</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! Once I figure out how to get these back into rows I will share the result!

Comment: That's wonderful to hear. Remember to mark the solution as an answer by pressing the checkmark.